# How to make sql query using group by data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table which look like below:

```
     id        name     
---|------|------------|
   |   1  | IP2.0-v1.0 |
   |   2  | IP2.0-v2.0 |
   |   3  | IP1.0-v1.0 |
   |   4  | IP1.1-v1.0 |
```

I would like to have group by result such as below:

```
     name        count     
---|----------|------------|
   |   IP2.0  |     2      |
   |   IP1.0  |     1      |
   |   IP1.1  |     1      |
```

How can I manage to get SQL query using group by?

> Select name,count(*) from table_a GROUP BY ...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (NAME,1,5), COUNT(*) FROM table_a GROUP BY SUBSTRING (NAME,1,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a subquery to do the substring before the group by

```
select nameSub, count(*) from
(select id, substring(name,1,5) as nameSub from table)
group by nameSub
```

Answer (score 1):

[**MySQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59229/2/0) and [**SQL Server Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59229/1/0):

```
SELECT LEFT(name, 5), count(*) 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY LEFT(name, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT   SUBSTRING(Name,1,CHARINDEX('-',Name)-1) AS Name, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM     table_a
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Name,1,CHARINDEX('-',Name)-1)
```

`SUBSTRING` is useful if the length of `Name` vary

Answer (score 1):

Try with `SUBSTRING( str FROM pos FOR len )`

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(`name` from 1 for 5) as name_res, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM @TABLE
GROUP BY name_res;
```